# Calling method from ViewModel cause System.NullReferenceException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, cross-platform, nullreferenceexception

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms, and I'm developing an app for cross-platform. In the app, users need to login to Facebook and Twitter to participate in some particular event. So I set a static login function in the setting page and join the event page. I need to check if the login was successful and show the username on the page every time the user opens the setting page. so I decided to call the checking method in the code behind, in the OnAppearing method. But it would call NullReferenceException. if I just moved the whole code from the checking method, nothing changed on the setting page.

Here's my code behind:

```
    public SettingAct()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        (BindingContext as SettingViewModel).CekLogin();
    }
```

The checking method on my ViewModel:

```
    internal void CekLogin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LoginCheck");
        if (SessionManager.FacebookLogin())
        {
            FacebookName = SessionManager.FacebookName();
            FbImage = "fb_sett_active.png";
            Console.WriteLine("Facebook logged in");
        }
        else
        {
            FacebookName = "Facebook";
            FbImage = "fb_sett.png";
            Console.WriteLine("Facebook not logged in");
        }

        if (SessionManager.TwitterLogin())
        {
            TwitterName = SessionManager.TwitterName();
            TwitImage = "twitter_sett_active.png";
            Console.WriteLine("Twitter logged in");
        }
        else
        {
            TwitterName = "Twitter";
            TwitImage = "twitter_sett.png";
            Console.WriteLine("Twitter not logged in");
        }
    }
```

I'm confused as to why it didn't work, cause I'm doing the same thing on my main page, where I refresh the user points every time the main page appears.

```
   (BindingContext as MainViewModel).RefreshKuliahLogPoint();
```

Please let me know in the comment for any details you need, and I hope you can understand my question even with my bad English.

Comment: Did you set the `BindingContext` in code behind or xaml ?

Comment: in my xaml, ContentPage.BindingContext tag.

Comment: Could you share the sample to github so that I can test it on my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BindingContext property will return null until you actually set it to something.

```
public SettingAct()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new SettingViewModel();
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    (BindingContext as SettingViewModel).CekLogin();
}
```

Comment: I set the BindingContext in my XAML file. is it no good? Btw, there are two semicolons in your code. Edit: after implementing your suggestion, I still got the NullReferenceException (ERROR: Caught exception in OnAfterSave at 290), but my code works anyway. is it OK?